# Stripe-Subscription-Plan-Change

Tags: django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, subscription, python-stripe-api

The user take a subscription , created a checkout page link using stripe API and using that link user can take subscription. But When a user wants to change his/her taken base plan to standard plan then how to do that? if we wrote a subscription modify API then how we pay than amount while changing a base plan to standard plan?

To know while a user change the existing base plan to standard plan then how to pay the additional amount/amount due using stripe payment gateway?

Comment: you can look at this guide https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade. It explains the needed steps.

Comment: how to pay the amount? from user side